# Trying to install the PEAR mail package so I can send Emails in php but I keep getting an error

Tags: php, pear

I go into My cmd prompt and use this command: `pear install --alldeps Mail`,

but I keep getting this:

```
C:\xampp\php>pear install --alldeps Mail WARNING: "pear/Auth_SASL" is deprecated in favor of "pear/Auth_SASL2" downloading Mail-1.4.1.tgz ...
Starting to download Mail-1.4.1.tgz (21,756 bytes) ........done: 21,756 bytes downloading Net_SMTP-1.8.0.tgz ...
Starting to download Net_SMTP-1.8.0.tgz (14,399 bytes) ...done: 14,399 bytes
downloading Net_Socket-1.2.2.tgz ... Starting to download Net_Socket-1.2.2.tgz (6,903 bytes) ...done: 6,903 bytes
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\Mail
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\Net_Socket
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\Net_SMTP\docs
```

and I am still unable to use the mail package I don't know if Im doing this incorrectly or not? How do I install the Pear mail package.

Comment: You should look into Composer and PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a permission problem. Are you able to manually create those directories? If not, you need to do it as admin.